# Using a FormView with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using a FormView control to edit a record fetched using a LinqDataSource. In essence, the markup for the FormView and the data source looks like this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="RuleInstancePropertiesFormView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RuleInstanceId"
DataSourceID="RuleInstanceDataSource" DefaultMode="Edit" Visible="false"
CssClass="PropertiesTable">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="RuleInstanceId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RuleInstanceId") %>' />

    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RuleInstanceNameTextBox" 
                        runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Bind("Rule.Name") %>' />

    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="LimitIndexTextBox"
                        runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Bind("LimitIndex") %>' />
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="RuleInstanceDataSource" runat="server"
    ContextTypeName="Questionnaire.QuestionnairesDataContext"
    TableName="RuleInstances" EnableUpdate="true">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

The record I am editing has a foreign key reference to another table, namely the "Rule" table. In the FormView, I need to edit fields in this foreign key table (I have a binding to the Rule.Name field in the above code).

When I try to save my changes, the local field (LimitIndex) is saved correctly in the database, but the foreign field (Rule.Name) isn't. I'm a bit puzzled by this, as the FormView correctly fetches the current value of Rule.Name, but refuses to persist it back to the LINQ object.

I hope anyone can help, thanks :)

Comment: Alternatively, if I could specify a custom projection object to use in my LINQ query, then I could specify my data binding between that projection object and my Rule object (with foreign table references). It just seems like the LinqDataSource doesn't allow using custom select queries if it also should support automatic updates :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found an alternative (but not elegant) solution. I use an ObjectDataSource instead of a LinqDataSource. I have then defined an class

```
public class RuleInstanceProjection {
    public RuleInstanceProjection(){}

    // Bind properties from the LINQ object.
    public RuleInstanceProjection(RuleInstance instance) { ... }

    public int RuleInstanceId {get; set;}
    public string Rule_Name {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

The object above takes a RuleInstance as constructor, and updates its own properties with all the values that I need in the FormView. I then configure the ObjectDataSource to use another custom class, RuleInstanceProjectionDS, as data source. This class handles updates and inserts of my custom RuleInstanceProjection class:

```
public class RuleInstanceProjectionDS
{
    public RuleInstanceProjectionDS() { }

    public RuleInstanceProjection GetRuleInstance(int ruleInstanceId)
    { /* Retrieve the RuleInstance, and instantiate 
         a RuleInstanceProjection object */ }

    public void SaveInstanceProjection(InstanceProjection projection)
    { /* Map fields back to the LINQ objects and submit. */ }
}
```

I can therefore handle all mappings in these two classes. Now, I only have to decide if this is actually better than updating the GUI controls directly...

I must say it isn't the most elegant solution, and I hope there will be a better data binding framework in later versions of ASP.NET. The current one only seems to handle the most trivial cases :(.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying which table to use as a datasource using the TableName property. This controls which table Linq2Sql will update and so is limiting the update to just the RulesInstances table.

Comment: Okay, that was what I thought. Thanks! Do you have any ideas as to what I can do then? I think the only option I have right now is to do all the data binding in the code-behind.

Comment: Yes unfortunately you're going to have do this in the code behind.